# Confused with infinity notation in limits

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I'm taking a course on real analysis and I wondered if  $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is the same as   $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ but why would one use +∞ notation then.. or does $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ signify $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)$ Thanks.

Comment: Different text books may use different notation.  To answer your question, yes, they are the same.  Just as we typically use $1, 2, 3, \cdots$ to denote positive numbers.

Comment: This usually looks like this..(IMHO)  We don't put the + sign to write positive numbers...When using limits it usually means $\to \infty \equiv \to +\infty$. Wolfy says so too..

Comment: $\infty$ and $+\infty$ are the same just as $1$ and $+1$ are.

Comment: Regarding $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)$, I don't think I have ever seen this. Also you will never(?) see $\sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty}\,a(k)$

Comment: Sometimes people use $+\infty$ purely to avoid confusion with $-\infty$, as in e.g. $\lim_{x\to0^\pm}\tfrac1x=\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

If the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ means exactly the same as $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}$. You sometimes see it when $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}$ is also under consideration, to highlight the distinction; but it is never necessary.

And for further reading: if the domain of $f$ is something more exotic, such as $\Bbb C\cup\infty$ (the [extended complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)) or $\Bbb R\cup\infty$ (the [projectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line)), then there is only one infinity, denoted by $\infty$. So $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}$ is not used in such contexts.